# What prototype function does `Array.prototype.push` use on the passed elements

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a resolver class that does some data validation and I want to also use it so it can be pushed into an array. Obviously I don't want to push the class but a specific object structure into the array.

```
type RoleReward = {
  roleId: Snowflake;
  rewardName: string;
  redeemed: boolean;
}

const resolver = new BaseRoleResolver();
const allRewards = new Array<RoelReward>();

allRewards.push(resolver);
```

and the resolvers all use this base class

```
export class BaseRoleResolver {
  roleId: Snowflake;
  rewardName: string;
  redeemed: boolean = false;

  (...)

  valueOf() {
    return {
      roleId: this.roleId,
      rewardName: this.rewardName,
      redeemed: this.redeemed,
    };
  }
}
```

Can I make use of Javascript calling some prototype function on the class that I can just overwrite to return the custom object format instead of the entire class object?

EDIT: Clarified first code snippet

Comment: So you want to change `allRewards.push(resolver);` into `allRewards.push(resolver.valueOf());`?

Comment: @trincot sorry I accidentally edited out the push when shortening and anonymising names. The async stuff has nothing to do with the question it's just in there because I copied it out of the project as a code snippet.

Comment: @Bergi yes but ideally without specifically calling valueOf

Comment: `valueOf` is used by JavaScript to get a primitive value. Defining it to return a non-primitive is bad practice. Use a different method name.

Comment: @trincot oh ya it will get a more sensible name now anyway that I have my answer. The `valueOf` was just what I understood to be how it should be done. Now I know it's not. Thanks for the answers and tips.

Comment: "*Obviously I don't want to push the class*" - why not? Where are you using the arrays, what for? The easiest solution would be to just have the class implement the `RoleReward` interface - which it already does!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What prototype function does `Array.prototype.push` use on the passed elements

None. It just puts whatever values you pass to it into the array.

> Can I make use of Javascript calling some method on the object that I can just overwrite?

No.

> I don't want to push the class but a specific object structure into the array.

Then you will have to write your code so it does that:

```
  for (const resolver of roleResolvers) {
    if (
      (await resolver.qualifiesForReward(validOrders, email)) &&
      !resolver.alreadyRedeemed(allRewards)
    ) {
      allRewards.push(resolver.valueOf());
//                             ^^^^^^^^^
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Will just make a getter out of it so it looks nicer in the code. Thank you very much.